# People say "false positives" in request smuggling. What does it mean?

Tags: http, request-smuggling

I always see "false positives" or "false negatives" in [HTTP request smuggling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_request_smuggling) forum posts. What does it mean?

Example: *[HTTP Desync Attacks: Request Smuggling Reborn](https://portswigger.net/research/http-desync-attacks-request-smuggling-reborn)*

Comment: These phrases are not really specific to information security. A false positive means simply that the result looks positive (like: antivirus claims to detect a virus) but it is actually not a real positive (antivirus __wrongly__ detected a virus) - thus a false positive. And this can also happen with vulnerability scanners (claims to be vulnerable, but is not) etc. A false negative is similar - something which is actually positive (i.e. is a virus) is not detected as such.

Comment: This question is lacking any evidence of research. Have you googled the terms?

Answer (score 2):

These are terms used a lot in different areas, antivirus software (AV), [IDS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrusion_detection_system), and vulnerability scanning. These are ways to say if a detection came out wrong or right and in what way. The terms are universal, so it always goes like this:

A true positive is when things are working out the way it should be. The results are accurate no mistakes.

A false positive is when it detects something that is not there. It's basically the scanner mistaking something legitimate or nothing to be worry about for something bad. A lot can be annoying.

Example:

1. You scan a system with an AV and it detects your *email* client as malware. Is it? No, but it's a mistake. (Although the example used AV, the concept is the same.)
2. Your spam filter detects that important business message as spam.

A false negative is when it detects nothing when something is there. These are more dangerous as it means things are slipping past the scans.

Example:

1 You really have a malware email client, but the AV failed to recognize that.

2. The spam filter keeps letting those annoying emails in when obviously it's spam.

Answer (score 0):

- False positive:

  You send requests with malformed Content-Length and Transfer-Encoding headers. When one of these responses times out, it flags it as [HTTP request smuggling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_request_smuggling).
- False negative:

  When HTTP request smuggling exists, but a [web application firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application_firewall) (WAF) or anything else blocks it.